# Добавить слово в input text

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Есть input type="text". Мне нужно, чтобы при загрузке страницы пайп (вертикальная черта) уже была в поле ввода (не нужно было нажимать на поле ввода, чтобы начать вводить текст) и, чтобы в поле ввода в начало было добавлено слово и пробел, которые нельзя было стереть.

Comment: Слово можно добавить в атрибут value="Слово ". Для автоматического выбора поля есть атрибут autofocus для input, но он добавлен только в HTML5

Comment: Да, autofocus- то, что нужно. Про слово забыл написать, что нужно, чтобы это слово нельзя было стереть, так что value - не подойдёт.

Comment: Чтобы нельзя было стереть, без велосипеда на javascript можно сделать поле ввода таким образом: <div id="wrap"><div id="prefix">Слово </div><input type="text"></div>. Элементу #wrap добавить рамку и другие стили, как у обычного input, а сам input сделать прозрачным. Элементу #prefix дать display:inline-block, чтобы строку не переводил, и готово

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Курсор в поле ввода при загрузке страницы - это атрибут autofocus у input:

```
<input type="text" name="name" autofocus>
```

В IE не работает, но есть элементарный полифил:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))) {
    $('[autofocus]:first').focus();
  }
});
```

Чтобы было добавлено слово и пробел - это можно двумя способами:

- На бекенде, при рендере html добавить в инпут атрибут `value="ваше слово "`
- На фронтенде, в js-скрипте

js-скрипт будет почти такой же, как полифил выше:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))) {
    $('[autofocus]:first').val("ваше слово ");
  }
});
```

При желании вы можете их совместить в один.

UPD: Из комментариев к вопросу "Чтобы слово с пробелом нельзя было стереть" - тогда это слово лучше просто подписать слева от инпута, никак не связывая с инпутом. В самом инпуте вписываем лишь "добавку", и на сервер отсылаем только эту добавку, а на сервере уже разруливаем как нужно (например склеиваем добавку с вашим словом и сохраняем в таком виде в БД).